# VSCODE Installation crashes on 64 bit Win7 Sp1

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCODE Installation crashes on my 64 bit Win7 Sp1.
I guess the reason is likely that I only have one drive (C:\).
VSCODE might want to access some path on D:\. 

some details,

I doubleclick the installation exe file. It shows a dialog saying "update has stopped working" with two options, "debug" and "close program". After I click "close program", another dialog shows up and says "Installation has failed" and a few other texts telling me to check the setup log for more info or contact the author. I've also tried run as administrator. Nothing changes.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? This works for me fine even though I also have one drive. You can also use help > report issue to send the team more detail.

Comment: I doubleclick the installation exe file. It shows a dialog saying "update has stopped working" with two options, "debug" and "close program". After I click "close program", another dialog shows up and says "Installation has failed" and a few other texts telling me to check the setup log for more info or contact the author. I've also tried run as administrator. Nothing changes.

Comment: You running the installation as admin? If not try that (right click -> run as administrator).